# File dialog always returns alpha order

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I'm creating an application which plots data in files.  The first file plotted defines the origin to which all other data is transformed relative to.  AFAICT, the QFileDialog always returns files in alphabetical order, regardless of selection order.

Is there a way to return the data ordered by selection?

To illustrate, create a folder with files named something A, B, C or 1, 2, 3.  Regardless of the manner they're selected or appear in File Name line edit, the list of paths returned is in alphabetical order.

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

MYDIR = (os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '/Desktop/numbered').replace("\\", "/")

def on_button_pressed():
    paths, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
        directory = MYDIR,
        caption='Open',
        filter=(
            'All (*.*)'
        ))

    for i, path in enumerate(paths):
        print(i, path, flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open")
    button.pressed.connect(on_button_pressed)

    button.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT** An implementation of @musicamate's response which may hang:

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


MYDIR = (os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '/Desktop/numbered').replace("\\", "/")


class SelectionOrderFileDialog(QtWidgets.QFileDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setOption(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        self.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)

        list_view = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView, 'listView')
        self.selection_model = list_view.selectionModel()
        self.selection_model.selectionChanged.connect(self.check_selection)

        self.current_selection = []

    def check_selection(self):
        active_selection = []

        for index in self.selection_model.selectedRows():
            path = index.data(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole)
            active_selection.append(path)

        updated_current_selection = []

        for path in self.current_selection:
            if path in active_selection:
                updated_current_selection.append(path)
                active_selection.remove(path)

        updated_current_selection.extend(active_selection)
        self.current_selection[:] = updated_current_selection

        print(self.current_selection, flush=True)


def on_button_pressed():

    # Works fine when called as...
    # dialog = SelectionOrderFileDialog()

    # Causes hangs on Open
    dialog = SelectionOrderFileDialog(
        directory = MYDIR,
        caption='Open',
        filter=(
            'text (*.txt)'
            ';;python (*.py)'
            ';;All (*.*)'
        ))

    dialog.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open")
    button.resize(300, 25)
    button.pressed.connect(on_button_pressed)

    button.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Probably not. Instead of letting them select multiple files at once, require them to select files one at a time. Then you can add the files to a global list each time they select, and keep them in the order that they selected.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.

Comment: It can be done, but not by using the static methods: you need to create a QFileDialog instance, configure it to your needs and connect with the [`filesSelected`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#filesSelected) signal and implement a method that "keeps" the ordering when the selection changes.

Comment: @musicamante Even with a native dialog?

Comment: @LoremIpsum what do you mean?

Comment: @musicamante My bad.  Modifying the dialog window itself, such as inserting extra widgets, requires using the non-native dialog option.  You're right, simply inheriting/connecting signals doesn't affect that option.

Comment: It looks like the fileSelected and filesSelected signals aren't called until Open is clicked.  At that point they're already in alpha order.  The currentChanged signal doesn't appear to capture files selected with Control or Shift.  The filesSelected method, when used in the slot connected to currentChanged, doesn't appear to detect Control or Shift selected files either.  Is there another signal or method you're thinking of?

Comment: @LoremIpsum Sorry, I forgot that `filesSelected` is only emitted when the dialog is accepted and `currentChanged` isn't emitted when a *non-current* is deselected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such level of control cannot be achieved by using static methods, but it can be done by using an instance of QFileDialog.

The only requirement is to avoid the native dialog, so that we can access one of the file views (a non-native QFileDialog has a list view and a tree view), and then connect to the `selectionChanged` signal of its selection model.
Then, everytime the signal is emitted, we check with the current *ordered* selection, remove paths that already exist and build a new list by extending with the new elements.

```
    def showDialog(self):
        def checkSelection():
            selection = []
            for index in selectionModel.selectedRows():
                path = index.data(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole)
                selection.append(path)
            newOrderedPaths = []
            for path in orderedPaths:
                if path in selection:
                    newOrderedPaths.append(path)
                    selection.remove(path)
            newOrderedPaths.extend(selection)
            orderedPaths[:] = newOrderedPaths

        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)
        dialog.setOption(dialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        dialog.setFileMode(dialog.ExistingFiles)
        listView = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView, 'listView')
        selectionModel = listView.selectionModel()
        selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(checkSelection)

        orderedPaths = []

        dialog.exec_()

        print(orderedPaths)
```

Obviously, the same can be done using a subclass.

Comment: Thank you!  I notice that occasionally the application hangs on dialog.exec_().  It's at a rate of something like 1 in 6, sometimes on the second open.  It's suggested that it's due to event processing.  Putting a processEvents() prior to dialog.exec_() or within the closeEvent() doesn't resolve the issue.  Moving the widget to a MainWindow for object persistence produces the same issue.  I suppose I could run the dialog in a separate thread so that it has it's own event loop, but talk about overkill.  Any advice?  Open a separate SO question?  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24892872/

Comment: Trying to run the dialog in a separate thread won't work, as ALL UI object *must* reside on the main thread. Also, the QDialog `exec` *does* create its own event loop. With your given code what you're describing should not happen, you're not trying to execute the QApplication in another thread, are you?

Comment: I'm running it basically as written.  Within `on_button_pressed`, I create a dialog object and then run dialog.exec_().  The source of the problem appears related to filtering I try to set.  I'll post an edit...

Comment: @LoremIpsum I cannot reproduce your issue. Are you using some network resource that could be temporarily disabled and unreachable?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  There are network directories on my system, but those are not being actively viewed in the dialog.

Comment: It looks like it's something related to how the name filters are parsed or "passed into" `setFilter`/`setNameFilters` (internally) after parsing.  When I try to set the filter manually using `setFilter`, I get strange errors.  Doing `kwargs.get('filter')` gives a ";;" delimited list.  Calling `.split(';;')` in some circumstances throws `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`.  That makes no sense to me.  But, if that's happening silently during runtime, perhaps that's the culprit.  I seriously don't have time to keep messing with this.   Using `setNameFilters` appears to work.

Comment: The docs aren't clear to me what the 'filters' input is for `setFilter`/`setNameFilters` other than a ';;' delimited string.  Both say 'filters', with an 's' for plural.  Maybe `setFilter` takes different inputs or a different input format than `setNameFilters`?  Yet still, sometimes the filter works, sometimes it doesn't.  When the filter doesn't work, the hang occurs.  It's bizarre.  Anyway, I mention all this not for 'extended discussion' but for prosperity.  Hopefully it can save someone else hours of chasing.

Comment: @LoremIpsum I admit that's always been confusing. But, in any case, you could hardly have real runtime problems by inverting them: [`setNameFilters()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setNameFilters) only accepts a list of strings, while [`setFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setFilter) can only work with QDir.Filter flags: if you use the wrong argument type, you'll get an exception for that. But that would just raise the exception (and crash if not managed) for the wrong type, and should have nothing to do with the hanging. Also, using the combo makes that internal.